# deploying base note for HPC cluster in server 2012R2 hangs

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, deployment, pxe-boot, hpc

We are in the process of evaluating server 2012R2 standard with HPC pack for a small cluster of nodes (about 40 to start with - the current setup has only one compute node).

For the moment we use old hardware to try out things and get a feeling for what we need. But now I'm stuck while bare metal deploying the base node.

**Provision Log:**

```
Time                Message
28-6-2015 15:19:56  Sending PXE command to boot node to WINPE (Expected boot time: 5-15 minutes)
28-6-2015 15:19:46  Sending PXE command to boot node to WINPE (Expected boot time: 5-15 minutes)
28-6-2015 15:19:43  Waiting for node to boot into WINPE
28-6-2015 15:19:43  Initiating configuration operations for template: VideoEncoder Base Template
28-6-2015 15:19:43  Computer account ENCODER1004 created
28-6-2015 15:19:42  The computer account ENCODER1004 does not exist; creating a new account in Active Directory.
28-6-2015 15:19:42  Searching for an existing account in Active Directory
28-6-2015 15:19:42  Connecting to domain controller: encoders.local
28-6-2015 15:19:42  Initiating provisioning operations for template: VideoEncoder Base Template
28-6-2015 15:19:42  Creating DHCP reservation 192.168.20.5 on scope 192.168.20.0
28-6-2015 15:19:41  Setting DHCP option 17 to iscsi:192.168.20.1::::iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:head-node-encoder1004-base-target
28-6-2015 15:19:41  Setting DHCP option 12 to encoder1004
28-6-2015 15:19:41  Setting DHCP option 203 to iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:encoder1004.encoders.local
28-6-2015 15:19:41  Creating a reservation for network adapter: FCAA14656038
28-6-2015 15:19:41  Mapping successful
28-6-2015 15:19:40  Mapping client [iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:encoder1004.encoders.local] to target LUN [ENCODER1004-BASE] on storage array [127.0.0.1]
28-6-2015 15:19:39  Remote disk disconnected
28-6-2015 15:18:52  Disconnecting remote disk
28-6-2015 15:18:37  Configuring bootloader
28-6-2015 15:18:20  Copying WinPE files
28-6-2015 15:18:16  Placing bootloader
28-6-2015 15:18:16  Mount successful at: C:\Windows\TEMP\larluozy.ekq
28-6-2015 15:17:41  Connection established, mounting disk
28-6-2015 15:17:40  Connecting to iSCSI target: 192.168.20.1 / iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:head-node-encoder1004-base-target
28-6-2015 15:17:40  Mapping successful
28-6-2015 15:17:39  Mapping client [iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:HEAD-NODE.encoders.local] to target LUN [ENCODER1004-BASE] on storage array [127.0.0.1]
28-6-2015 15:17:39  Base LUN creation complete
28-6-2015 15:17:39  Creation successful
28-6-2015 15:17:38  Creating base LUN "ENCODER1004-BASE"
28-6-2015 15:17:37  Setting boot-initiator information
28-6-2015 15:17:37  Associating template VideoEncoder Base Template with node ENCODERS\ENCODER1004
28-6-2015 15:17:37  Moving node ENCODERS\ENCODER1004 from state Unknown to state Provisioning
28-6-2015 15:17:37  Assigning template VideoEncoder Base Template to node ENCODER1004
```

**WebCam capture of base-node-screen:**

(to little rep to post an image - need 10+ - so here come the last few lines typed)

```
Contacting Server: 192.168.20.1.....

PXE->EB: !PXE at 8AC4:0070. entry point at 8AC4:0100
         UNDI code segment 8AC4:3BE8. data segment 7E79:C4B0 (505-571kB)
         UNDI device is PCI 03:00.0 type DIX+802.3
         505kB free base memory after PXE unload
iPXI initialising devices...ok

iPXE 1.0.0+ (d739) ..


net0: fc:aa.. ..60:38 using undionly on UNDI-PCI03:00.0 (open)
  [Link:up, TX:0 TXE:0 RX:0 RXE:0]
Configuring (net0: fc:aa.. ..60:38)...... ok
net0: 192.168.20.5/255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.20.1
Root path: iscsi:192.168.20.1::::iqn.1991-05.com.microsift:head-node-encoder1004-base-target
Registered SAN device 0x80
Booting from SAN device 0x80
```

Installing via PXE on the node worked, if there is a local HDD (happend accidentally).
However bare metal stops with the screen and log posted above. The iSCSI drive is not connected at that point.

**Setup:**

- ***server:*** DELL 1520 laptop with 2GB RAM + 135 GB HDD

  - OS: Server 2012R2 Standard (eval) + HPC Pack 2012 SP1
  - acts as: AD, DNS, DHCP, WDS, HPC controller and iSCSI target
  - PXE-loader: 
    [iPXI chainloaded](http://ipxe.org/howto/chainloading)
- ***base-node:*** Gigabyte ITX board with Celeron n2807, 4GB RAM, no HDD (we need Quick Sync not pure CPU power)

  - OS: Server 2012R2 Standard Core (eval, no activation key) **OR** Win8.1 embedded industry with volume licence and activation key embedded in the image
  - PXE boot enabled, auto bood at power loss enabled

**Question:** What can I do to resolve the problem or at least to find the cause of the problem?

*Im a programmer not an admin so my knowledge of that stuff is limited, but in a tiny startup like ours there is no one else to do it. So any help and pointers are more than welcome. We are aware that we are pushing it with this hardware. A first test setup will be ordered in the next few days. But I would like to get this to work before to see if we need stuff we overlooked so far.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems problem is a combination of old hardware and possible not provides network drivers. At least that is my guess.

We recieved the new hard ware and now the deployment process continues past this point. (How ever it now hangs at the end. Can not join the domain.)

In case you wonder. The new hardware is:

Server
ASRock J1900D2Y, 16 GB, 3TB HDD

Base-NODE
ASRock Q1900TM-ITX, 4 GB, no HDD